# "invalid host header" starting Skeleton Web Application for Hyperledger Developer Guide tutorial

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I'm going through the [Hyperledger Developer Guide Tutorial](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/tutorials/developer-guide.html).  I've done the steps through *Generate REST API* without any trouble.  After going through the *Generate your Skeleton Web Application* section, I don't see any problems in the shell output but when I try to navigate to port 4200 as instructed, I get a mostly-blank screen that says `Invalid Host header`.

In the #composer channel on Rocketchat, I saw someone have a [similar problem](https://chat.hyperledger.org/channel/composer?msg=eiTa4KQCmit8C5wo7).  Someone suggested that this was:

> because the directory specified in your hlfv1 profile under
>   keyValStore cannot be created or accessed. Most likely you have
>   specified a directory such as /home/fred/.hfc-key-store but the user
>   fred doesn't exist so the directory /home/fred doesn't exist. One
>   solution would be just to create the directory path yourself.

I checked and my directory is ok:

```
ibmadmin@pfuntner1:~/repos$ cat /home/ibmadmin/.composer-connection-profiles/hlfv1/connection.json
{
    "type": "hlfv1",
    "orderers": [
       { "url" : "grpc://localhost:7050" }
    ],
    "ca": { "url": "http://localhost:7054",
            "name": "ca.org1.example.com"
    },
    "peers": [
        {
            "requestURL": "grpc://localhost:7051",
            "eventURL": "grpc://localhost:7053"
        }
    ],
    "keyValStore": "/home/ibmadmin/.composer-credentials",
    "channel": "composerchannel",
    "mspID": "Org1MSP",
    "timeout": "300"
}
ibmadmin@pfuntner1:~/repos$ ls -ld /home/ibmadmin/.composer-credentials
drwxrwxr-x 2 ibmadmin ibmadmin 4096 Sep 13 15:11 /home/ibmadmin/.composer-credentials
ibmadmin@pfuntner1:~/repos$ ls -l /home/ibmadmin/.composer-credentials
total 24
-rw-r--r-- 1 ibmadmin ibmadmin  246 Sep 13 15:10 114aab0e76bf0c78308f89efc4b8c9423e31568da0c340ca187a9b17aa9a4457-priv
-rw-r--r-- 1 ibmadmin ibmadmin  182 Sep 13 15:11 114aab0e76bf0c78308f89efc4b8c9423e31568da0c340ca187a9b17aa9a4457-pub
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ibmadmin ibmadmin  246 Sep 13 15:11 2a176af765281bb00394c2427cb7acc679d3eb9b504703eaba8c32a5a0f1a61c-priv
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ibmadmin ibmadmin  182 Sep 13 15:40 2a176af765281bb00394c2427cb7acc679d3eb9b504703eaba8c32a5a0f1a61c-pub
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ibmadmin ibmadmin  962 Sep 13 15:40 admin
-rw-r--r-- 1 ibmadmin ibmadmin 1024 Sep 13 15:11 PeerAdmin
ibmadmin@pfuntner1:~/repos$
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?

## Update

I added this statement:

```
$ diff -C5 node_modules/@angular/cli/tasks/serve.js.orig node_modules/@angular/cli/tasks/serve.js
*** node_modules/@angular/cli/tasks/serve.js.orig       2017-09-14 12:20:45.462357278 -0400
--- node_modules/@angular/cli/tasks/serve.js    2017-09-14 11:27:55.682265096 -0400
***************
*** 158,167 ****
--- 158,168 ----
          ui.writeLine(chalk.green(common_tags_1.oneLine `
        **
        NG Live Development Server is running on ${serverAddress}
        **
      `));
+         webpackDevServerConfiguration.disableHostCheck = true;
          const server = new WebpackDevServer(webpackCompiler, webpackDevServerConfiguration);
          return new Promise((_resolve, reject) => {
              server.listen(serveTaskOptions.port, serveTaskOptions.host, (err, _stats) => {
                  if (err) {
                      return reject(err);
$
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be webpack related, though I have not seen this issue myself.

e.g.
https://support.glitch.com/t/invalid-host-header/1413

Comment: Thanks, Dan.  That worked great.  I added this statement:

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get around this problem by replacing the 0.0.0.0 host parameter in package.json with my actual IP address. It is found in the scripts section of the package.json file:

```
"scripts": {
  "ng": "ng",
  "build": "ng build",
  "prepack": "npm run build",
  "start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.js --host 0.0.0.0",
  ...
```

After changing this and running "npm start", port 4200 is reachable from a remote host.